# Why for loop does not work in reverse

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Why this reverse for loop does not work?

```js
var a  =1;

for(i=100; i<0; i--){
    a = a+i;
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: `i > 0` instead of `i < 0`

Answer (score 7):

```
for(i=100; i>0; i--){
    a = a+i;
}
```

Your condition was not correct

Comment: Ok now I understand the mistake that I was doing.
The second condition ( i>0) must be read as:
Keep doing the operation till the second condition is true.

I was convicend that the second condition had to be read in this way:
Keep doing till the second condition becomes true, this is why I have used i<0.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is not correct

```
  for(i=100; i>0; i--){
        a = a+i;
    }
```